# File is not uploading giving error "File is not uploaded please try again"?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, file-upload

i'ma beginner and i'm trying to upload a file to `uploads/` folder from this [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php) but as i run my program after submit it's showing error `There was an error uploading the file, please try again!` can you tell me what's wrong here??

form.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form image</title>
</head>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="post" name="changer">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" accept="image/jpeg">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

uploader.php

```
<?php
//where the file is going to be placed..
$target_path="uploads/";

$target_path=$target_path.basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], $target_path)){
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
        " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: try `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)`

Comment: thnkas  it's working can you tell me why we use here `tmp_name'???

Comment: `['uploadedfile']['name']` is the actual name of the file that u have choosen, `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']` is the temp name of the file where the file is stored on temp folder once you initiate the upload and the code will move that file from ur temp folder to the server.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty you should post as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)
```

You are using

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'], $target_path)
```

This will not work since the file is stored in the temp folder after the upload is initiated and while moving the file it must know the temp name so that the file could be moved from temp folder to the server.